# wget speed result as pass or fail

Tags: linux, bash, wget

I'm using the following to output the result of a download speed test

```
get -O /dev/null http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/10MB.zip 2>&1 | grep --only-matching '\([0-9.]\+ [KM]B/s\)'
```

ie

10.5 MB/s

what i'd like to be able to do is have it echo a result as well ie

if speed=>5 MB/s then echo "pass" else echo "fail"

so final output would be

PASS                  7 MB/s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
| awk ' { if (($1 > 10) && ($2 == "MB/s")) { printf("SPEED IS TOO DAMN HIGH - %s\n", $0); } elif (($1 > 5) && ($2 == "MB/s")) { printf("PASS - %s\n", $0); } else { printf ("FAIL - %s\n", $0); } } '
```

at the end of your command line.

Comment: works perfect thanks, just had another thought is their a way to add a word if the speed is too high ie if speed >10.5 MB/s then echo too high

Answer (score 1):

just a couple of changes need to be done really. you need to capture the output of your command using command substitution:

```
speed=$( wget -O /dev/null http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/10MB.zip 2>&1 | grep --only-matching '\([0-9.]\+ [KM]B/s\)' )
```

So the command inside the $( ) gets executed and it's stdout is assigned to the variable $speed.

```
root@host$ speed=$( wget -O /dev/null http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/10MB.zip 2>&1 | grep --only-matching '\([0-9.]\+ [KM]B/s\)' )
root@host$ echo $speed
5.50 MB/s
```

SO now we just need to compare the speed against your target. but the units could cause an issue So:

```
root@host$ val=${speed%% *}
root@host$ echo $val
5.50
root@host$ units=${speed##* }
root@host$ echo $units
MB/s
```

the construct ${var%%pattern} means strip the longest match of pattern from the right hand side of the value of var and return the result.
${var##patter} does the same but from the left hand side.

so now we can go ahead and check

```
root@host$ if [[ ${units} == "MB/s" && $val > "5.0" ]]; then 
> echo "PASS $speed"
> else
> echo "FAIL $speed"
> fi
PASS 5.50 MB/s
root@host$
```

so here we make sure we're in MB/s then ensure that the val is greater than your target speed.